# Importing brokerage QFX files into GnuCash

Tags: gnucash, ofx

I'm trying to figure out how to import QFX files from my brokerage into GnuCash. I have read the documentation about investments [here](https://lists.gnucash.org/docs/C/gnucash-guide/chapter_invest.html), but I'm having some problems getting it to work correctly. First problem:

I have several brokerage accounts set up in the following hierarchy:

```
Investments
  Brokerage Account #1
    Money Market Fund
    [various mutual funds]
  Brokerage Account #2
    Money Market Fund
    [various mutual funds]
```

The money market funds are the same fund across all accounts and are assigned to the same commodity. Money-market transactions for account #1 should show up under account #1; ditto for account #2. However, when I import QFX files of transactions, money-market transactions for account #2 are erroneously going into account #1, which happens to be the first one I set up in GnuCash.

Is this a known bug/limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

GnuCash "learns" and remembers how to treat different transaction types during the import process.

Without having tried to replicate your issue, my best guess is that GnuCash recognises your money market fund as being a fund that it has imported before, so it treats it the same way that it did before - by importing it into Brokerage Account #1.

A workaround that you might try is to edit the QFX file before import into GnuCash to change "money market fund" into "money market fund #2" or something similar so that the data from Broker #2 appears to GnuCash as something different to the data from Broker #1.  QFX is a proprietary format, but you may be able to edit (find and replace) directly or you may have to convert the file to CSV first.